# Template matching with multiple templates

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I am doing a project based on template matching using open-Cv. Here i need to check my source image with multiple templates an identify the correct template. The code is working perfectly for single template, but for multiple images i need to close the output window for every template. Although it matches correctly for respective template.kind of stuck here. Following is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os,sys
import os.path
import cv2, glob
images=glob.glob(r'D:\python\template\Country\*.jpg')

for image in images:
img_rgb = cv2.imread(r'D:\python\EURO-10-F.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread(image,0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

print (img_gray.shape)
r = 500.0 / img_gray.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(img_gray.shape[0] * r))

resized1 = cv2.resize(img_rgb, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)    
resized2 = cv2.resize(img_gray, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)


res = cv2.matchTemplate(resized2,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.5
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)


for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
cv2.rectangle(resized1,pt,(pt[0]+w,pt[1]+h),(0,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('detected',resized1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I was trying a for loop but dont know how to implement it getting error every time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for this. all you need to do is add a loop as follows:

```
if  a != ():
            cv2.imshow('detected',resized1)
            cv2.imshow('binary',binary)
break
```